# How to add a boolean value to a column when 2 different dataframes match on 2 columns in R?

Tags: r

I have 2 different dataframes. I want add a column to my second dataframe and have it assigned a value 0 or 1. In the case where df1$code == df2$code & df1$date == df2$date I want a 0 for these rows. A visual and reproducible example maybe makes it more easy to understand.

```
df1 <- data.frame(code = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), date = c(1,2,3,4))
df2 <- data.frame(code = c("A", "B", "E", "R", "V", "F"), date = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
df3 <- data.frame(code = c("A", "B", "E", "R", "V", "F"), date = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), value =c(1,1,0,0,0,0))
```

DF1

```
  code date
1    A    1
2    B    2
3    C    3
4    D    4
```

DF2

```
  code date
1    A    1
2    B    2
3    E    3
4    R    4
5    V    5
6    F    6
```

The resulting DF I want

```
  code date value
1    A    1     1
2    B    2     1
3    E    3     0
4    R    4     0
5    V    5     0
6    F    6     0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `%in%` to create a logical vector and then coerce it to binary with `as.integer` or `+`

```
df2$value <- +(df2$code %in% df1$code)
df2
#  code date value
#1    A    1     1
#2    B    2     1
#3    E    3     0
#4    R    4     0
#5    V    5     0
#6    F    6     0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
df2 %>% left_join(mutate(df1, value = 1)) %>%
  mutate(value  = coalesce(value, 0))
# Joining, by = c("code", "date")
#   code date value
# 1    A    1     1
# 2    B    2     1
# 3    E    3     0
# 4    R    4     0
# 5    V    5     0
# 6    F    6     0
```